# Adding data to an existing Excel File depending on columns and sheets

Tags: python, pandas, excel, append

I have two files, "template" and "catalogue". I want to add certain columns from catalogue to #template, taking into account that one column in catalogue named "PRODUCT TYPE" Determines which #Sheet it will go to in "template".

#the error I am getting is:
#in copy_to_template_sheet

writer.book=book

AttributeError: can't set attribute

I have tried multiple ways to fix it.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

catalogue_df = pd.read_excel(r"catalogue.xlsx")

template_excel_file = r"template.xlsx"
template_xls = pd.ExcelFile(template_excel_file, engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook(template_excel_file)

category_to_sheet_mapping = {
    'CATEGORY 1': 'Template-CATEGORY1',
    'CATEGORY 2': 'Template-CATEGORY2',
    'CATEGORY 3': 'Template-CATEGORY3',
#ETC.. ADDING ALL categories and the corresponding sheet names in template
}

column_mapping = {
    'column_1': 'Column_44',
    'column_2': 'Column_43',
    'column_3': 'column_234', 
    
    # etc, with all columns that I need to add data from into the template columns
}


def copy_to_template_sheet(category):
    sheet_name = category_to_sheet_mapping.get(category)
    if sheet_name:
        if sheet_name in book.sheetnames:
            template_df = pd.read_excel(template_excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
            for catalogue_col, template_col in column_mapping.items():
                template_df[template_col] = catalogue_df.loc[catalogue_df['PRODUCT TYPE'] == category, catalogue_col]
            startrow = template_df.shape[0] + 2  # Start data from the next row

            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template_excel_file, engine="openpyxl") 
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

            for r_idx, row in enumerate(dataframe_to_rows(template_df, index=False, header=False), start=startrow):
                for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                    sheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
                    sheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
        else:
            # If the sheet doesn't exist, create a new one with the data
            template_df = catalogue_df.loc[catalogue_df['PRODUCT TYPE'] == category, list(column_mapping.keys())]
            template_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=True)

# Loop through unique 'category' values in 'catalogue'
for category in catalogue_df['PRODUCT TYPE'].unique():
    copy_to_template_sheet(category)

# Save the changes to the 'template' Excel file
writer.save()
```